# Why right-continuity in probability distribution functions?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, piecewise-continuity, radon-nikodym

Let's look at the usual distribution function of a discrete probability distribution, say Poisson$(\lambda)$; call this function $F_X(x\vert\lambda)$. However, let's modify that function slightly so that it is left-continuous instead of right-continuous; call this function $\bar{F}_X(x\vert\lambda)$.

Now let $\mu$ be the counting measure. With the usual CDF, $\frac{dF(X\vert\lambda)}{d\mu} = \frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$. What happens when we take the Radon-Nikodyn derivative of the left-contnuous function, $\frac{d\bar{F}}{d\mu}$?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK we can only speak of a [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radon-NikodymDerivative.html) if there are two *measures* $\nu,\mu$ with: $$\nu(E)=\int_E f\;d\mu$$for every measurable $E$.

In that case $f$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ and can be denoted as $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$.

I understand that for $\mu$ you want to take the counting measure but what about $\nu$?

Just some affected (lost right-continuity) CDF at most indicates that - in order to determine a measure $\nu$ - we should go back to the original CDF and do it with the probability measure that is determined by this CDF.

That is an uninteresting situation because nothing changes then.

Comment: I think $\nu$ would be the Poisson probability measure but with left-continuity. Is that not a measure?

Comment: Being right-continuous or left-continuous *cannot* be classified as a *property of a measure*. It are properties of functions that are induced by measures, like $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$  and $G(x)=\mu((-\infty,x))$.

Comment: Okay, I mean tha $\nu$ is the measure that induces $\bar{F}$, and then take the RN derivation $d\nu / d\mu$. What goes wrong in taking that derivative or in creating that $\nu$ measure?

Comment: But $\overline F$ and $F$ are induced by *the same* measure $\nu$. The first as $\overline F(x)=\nu((-\infty,x))$ and the second as $F(x)=\nu((-\infty,x])$.

Comment: If we get the same measure whether the "CDF" is right-continuous or left-continuous, then why do we require right-continuity for a CDF? It seems like nothing goes wrong if we instead have left-continuity. The RN derivative would give the same PMF either way.

Comment: It is just a matter of choice. If a CDF is defined as $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ then it right-continuous. If it is defined as $\overline F(x)=P(X<x)$ then it is left-continuous. If conversely we want to retrieve the measure $\nu$ from CDF $F$ then we start with $\nu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$. If we want to retrieve it from $\overline F$ then we start with $\nu([a,b))=\overline F(b)-\overline F(a)$. The community has chosen for the first: $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$. But choosing the other option would not essentially change things. As you said: nothing goes wrong. But a choice must be made.

Comment: Would it then be fair to say we could define a CDF either way but not both ways simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, but IMV it is better to stick to one of both options in order to serve  the mathematical community. I dislike the phenomenom of authors that have distinct definitions for the same concept.